# End time of Magrib before it becomes Qaza

Tags: salat

I've heard people say a particular Ṣalāt is not Qaza until the beginning of the next prayer. I don't believe Magrib last long and get the feeling it's gone if I delay it by 15 miniutes or so. So brothers/sisters, I would like you to please tell me how long does Magrib Ṣalāt last before it becomes Qaza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dusk (the time when maghrib salaah is valid) is immediately followed by night, which is when the time for eesha salaah starts. That moment of transition from dusk to night is when maghrib salaah, if not prayed, becomes qadha. There is no intermediate time between the two prayers.

Having said that, it is a sin to delay maghrib salaah till it is so late that the time of eesha is (almost) upon you.

Answer (score -2):

yes sir if u want to know when is maghrib qaza (Delayed) its maghrib is valid till u can see some last rays in the sky so when maghrib prayer is on its still day time the light is there but delayed when that light is gone the skies start getting black thats the last and final time to pray salah